# why is default fetch size of jdbcTemplate is -1 in my spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am running spring boot 1.4.3 application. I am using `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` for connecting to SQL server database.

when I print out the default fetch size of jdbcTemplate and the driver, I get different values.

```
jdbcTemplate fetch size is -1
jtds driverfetch size is 100
```

This is how I get the fetch size from jdbcTemplate

```
int jtdsFetchSize = template.getDataSource().getConnection().createStatement().getFetchSize();
int jdcTemplateFetchSize = template.getFetchSize();
```

couple of questions

1. why jdbcTemplate fetch size is -1 while the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#getFetchSize--) says the default is zero.
2. in the above case, what is the actual fetch size when a statement executed. I am getting OOM memory error on my `select statments` and I am guessing a value of `-1`  indicates fetch size of ALL. but I can't find any documentation that supports it.

Thansk

Comment: The default isn't `0` it is `-1` and if you read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.3.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setFetchSize-int-_ that belongs the the version of Spring that spring boot 1.4.3 uses you will see that. For older versions it was 0, for newer spring versions it is -1. This value means use the drivers default so it will be 100. Also fetch size is something else as maxRows and I suspect it isn't so much the fetch size that is the problem but that you are retrieving too many result and convert them to objects.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks. yes, my select query do return a large records. I am thinking of using fetchSize to restrict how much I get each time and process. for example, with size of 100, I process 100 and get next 100 records..

Comment: As stated I doubt your fetch size will help you here (I suggest a read on what fetch size does, hint it isn't related to paging). But the problem is that in the end you have all the records in memory and that is probably your real issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `setMaxRows` rather than `setFetchSize`.
In my opinion, fetchSize is more to restrict the size of a *single* record and maxRows is to restrict the size of total records.
Therefore, maybe you can try to use `setMaxRows` next time.